# Nested resources. ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound within the Create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my route.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :invoices
 devise_for :users

 root to: 'pages#home'

  resources :users do
   resources :properties do
   resources :invoices
   end
  end
 end
```

Although I have no problems with the Create method in my Properties controller when creating a new property:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def index
  @properties = Property.all
 end

 def new
  @user =  current_user
  @property = @user.properties.build
 end

 def create
  @user =  current_user
  @property = @user.properties.create(property_params)
  @property.user_id = current_user.id
  if @property.save
   flash[:success] = "Nouveau Bien créé!"
  redirect_to user_properties_path
   else
    render 'static_pages/home'
   end
 end
```

This is completely different when creating an Invoice from the Properties Controller:

```
 class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @invoices = Invoice.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
   @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
   @invoice = @property.invoices.build
  end

  def create
   @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
   @invoice = @property.invoices.create(invoice_params)
    if @invoice.save
      redirect_to @invoices
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

   private

   def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:content)
   end
  end
```

Here is the form view:

```
   <%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
     <div class="form-inputs">
     <%= f.input :content %>
   </div>

   <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

The Rails servers keeps spewing :

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#create
Couldn't find Property without an ID

Why can it pick up (params[:property_id]) in the New method, but not in the Create method???

Comment: Could you please post the `invoice` form? I guess in the **form** you need to pass `user`, `property` as invoice has nested routes.

Comment: Done. Even when I edit the form with <%= simple_form_for(@property, @invoice) do |f| %>   it still causing a problem. This time the New view returns an error message: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Invoices#new
Showing /Users/rodolphegeant/code/mesloyers/app/views/invoices/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

can't write unknown attribute `builder`
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
6
              

<%= simple_form_for(@property, @invoice) do |f| %>

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. It would be `<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @property, @invoice] do |f| %>`

Comment: Hey Emu, Yes it's working, thanks! You need to post an answer so I can validate it and so you take credit for it. Thanks again

Comment: Posted as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in the form you need to pass **user**, **property** as `invoice` has nested routes.

It would be `<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @property, @invoice] do |f| %>`